# Font.Charset and TButton

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am setting Font.Charset to EASTEUROPE_CHARSET for all controls on my form. This works great for controls such as TLabel. But for controls that are simply a wrapper around a windows control, e.g. TButton, some characters are not displaying correctly.

Doing a Google search I have discovered that this is due to Font.Charset not matching the system codepage.

But I cannot find how to fix it. I am using Delphi 7, maybe this has been fixed in later Delphi's, I don't know.

Anyone help?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the system default language for non-unicode programs. It is in Control Panel, under regional languages and settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be multi-lingual in Delphi then you should just move up to the latest version. Working with code pages is a world of pain that disappears entirely when you embrace Unicode.

Comment: "just move up the the latest version". That made be laugh!

Comment: @AJ I don't get the joke, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 7 does not have Unicode Support (Though it should have support for some European Languages) so this may be your issue.  Delphi 2009 provides comprehensive Unicode Support to Delphi.